# Servlet IP filter

Tags: java, servlets, maven, servlet-filters, jboss7.x

i am deploying my web application in jboss as 7.1.1

i want to add an ip based filter in my web.xml, something like this

```
<filter>
<filter-name>Ip Filter</filter-name>
<filter-class>Class name</filter-class>
<allow-list></allow-list>
</filter-name>
```

i found a few filters like [this](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/LimitAccessToCertainClients) , but since i use maven i would like to have a filter that is available in the maven repositories that i can add dependency in my pom and start using in my web.xml
Can you point me to some existing available well tested implementation of servlet ip filter(would prefer it to be available in the maven repositories) that i can use?

Comment: why not add the dependency into your local Maven repository or your shared repository?

Comment: i just did that, added the class in the link to my local repository, but i just want some well tested implementation of servlet ip filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the page you've linked contains the RemoteHostFilter.java file. Just place that in your src/main/java folder (in the correct package of course) and you can use it. Since it seems to be a single class that would be the easiest way of using it.

And you need a maven proxy like nexus, artifactory or archiva. There you could upload thirdparty jars not available in public repositories.